# Unable to acess var/www/webmail/installer through web browser to install Roundcube

Tags: php, linux, var, webmail, roundcube

I am currently running an Ubuntu server and trying to install Roundcube through its web based interface.

I always get an error when i point to the var/www/webmail/installer which says :

> "The requested URL /webmail/installer was not found on this server."

Afterwards I decided to copy the files to the var/www/html. I copied all the files there and pointed my browser to the index.php (After deleting the apache html page).

Interestingly enough it worked. I tried to search the roundcube manual about how to troubleshoot this but didn’t find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that after a little fiddling around i figured out the problem.

I went to the etc/apache2/sites-available folder and configured the document root from

var/www/html

to

var/www/

And that fixed the problem.

Sorry for being dumb on the internet. 
I also tried to configure the apache2.conf file but that didn’t fix the problem